# Advice for simulating a high load on a web application -- realistic httperf parameters

Tags: http, load-testing, httperf

I have already selected httperf as the load testing tool to use.  I'm trying to figure out some realistic parameters to use, and if I need to use multiple machines to create more simultaneous connections, etc.  I've done some basic load testing before but nothing very sophisticated.

The only information I have about the estimated load is that I'd like to be able to handle 3 million hits in a day.  Part of my problem is that I don't have a good rule of thumb for how web traffic is "bursty".  Clearly, it depends on the specific site and is never the same twice.  But, maybe there is a rule of thumb that says, if your average load for a day is X requests per second, then you should plan for Y simultaneous connections and a peak rate of Z requests per second.

I've done a fair bit of searching around, and while I've found a number of explanations of the various load testing tools and their parameters, I've never seen a decent write up of how you can come up with realistic values to use for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be an answer you are looking for I have found JMeter to be an excellent resource across platform for various performance tests.

You can read more on JMeter from the Apache site @ http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/

Comment: I've used JMeter on other projects, and I found it quite valuable in constructing complex tests where I had to simulate a user logging in, clicking on some links, posting a form, etc.  But here I just need to slam a couple of well-known URLs, and my research has indicated that JMeter is more resource-intensive on the machine(s) running the test, so it is not as good for generating a ton of connections.

Comment: But to reiterate, my question is not about which tool to choose.  I want some guidelines for thinking about how to translate an estimated number of hits in 24 hours into realistic parameters for httperf.

Answer (score 0):

As it differs for every site and situation, here's my experience:

For a local audience, unless your site is aimed at kids/elderly, you'll find traffic is distributed roughly along (office drone) work hours. 8/24th of the day will carry all your traffic.
Peak is roughly 2 times the normal traffic in that period, usually arround lunchtime.

For a global audience, the traffic is distributed arround the day, with some drops (the pacific ocean is sparsely populated).

If you are linked from a major news site or do an interesting large TV/radio ad, you can expect traffic off the charts. No point in doing predictions there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am a little surprised by the 2:1 ratio for peak vs average -- I would have expected something higher.